# Multiple java socket connections

Tags: java, sockets

I have created this game bot where it connects to the game, and starts playing. 
My problem is that i can't start more than one of these as the other then won't work.

Is is possible that if i run 2 instances of the same program the sockets are interfering with each other ?  After all, they do connect to the same IP with the same port ?

And sometimes after i close(just closing cmd) the program is unable to connect again. Is that cause i didn't close the connections right ?. 
I hope this is enough else i'll just have to post my source code

Best regards.

Comment: make each "bot" run in it's own thread. This will let your program do more then one thing at the same time. Just google "threads java" and you will get all the info you need

Comment: Why won't it work to start more than one client? Is there an error logged or displayed? Is it your own game, or what? This forum is for concrete programming questions, most often associated with source code or similar. Not general "why doesn't my program work" type support. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq for guidelines in asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with a specific TCP port, then there is a close-wait period that this port cannot be claimed temporariliy for some time. also multiple programs cannot listen the same TCP port. Use threads.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to connect to the same socket/port several times. Actually a socket is a double peer: {client ip/ client port}{server ip/server port}. When you connect to a server, your client port is assigned dynamically. You will have a new and different client port per client. So it should work unless the server side forbid it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a server that listens for multiple connections.  A server is bound to a port and once that port is in use another application cannot use it.  So for the server just have one instance.  Multiple clients can connect to this IP/Port as long as the Server accepts multiple connections.

If a client connects to the server and the other clients stop working this may be because the server does not support multiple clients.  To do this you need to use multi threading in the server.  The server should accept a client socket and create a new instance of a client with it's own StreamReader/Writer objects.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html

Comment: I don't have access to the server. or the source code. But it's a game so i'm sure that it accepts multiple connections. My problem is that my client won't connect with more than one instance. Though i would like to make 10x clients run from my computer

Comment: Maybe they limit the connections at the Server side.  I.e. 1 thread per IP Address. If you know what commands to send to the Server, try opening multiple instances of Telnet up and connect to the server.  If it works this way then it must be your code, if not then the Server is stopping you connecting with multiple clients.